# Can't wrap my head around android drawable folders mdpi, xhdpi

Tags: android, resources

I can't wrap my head around the folders `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi`, are they meant for every kind of images or only for icons? The sizes in which my images are stored in there are really small, as you can see in this cheatsheet (click to enlarge):

[image: cheatsheet]

xhdpi is 96px. In my app 96px looks really blurry (click to enlarge):

[image: blurry]

So how should I store my image then?

Comment: this might be helpful https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the folders mdpi hdpi xhdpi and xxhdpi, are they meant for every kind of images or only for icons?

Most bitmap drawable resources should get density-specific versions, at least for a few densities.

> as you can see in this cheatsheet xhdpi is 96px

I see nothing in there saying that every image must be 96px for `xhdpi`. The standard action bar height and tab bar heights for `xhdpi` are 96px. That's it.

> In my app 96px looks really blurry.

That image should have a higher resolution, as you are using it in a UI element that is far larger than the action bar or a tab bar.

> So how should I store my image then?

Step #1: Determine your desired size for the image, in inches.

Step #2: Determine the resolution for the image in `dp`, by multiplying the size in inches from Step #1 by 160.

Step #3: Choose what densities you want to create specific artwork for. You might use the "Screen Sizes and Densities" section of [the Android device dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens) to give you some ideas.

Step #4: Determine the density-specific resolution for the image in `px`, for the densities from Step #3, by multiplying the `dp` value from Step #2 by the size factor shown in the upper-left infographic of that cheatsheet.

Step #5: Create `drawable` directories for the densities from Step #3 and create your artwork in those, sized based on the values from Step #4.

Comment: So, for instance, I have an image which I want to use which should cover 2/3 of the screen (what is achieved by using constraintlayout and guidelines), but how would I determine a size in inches for that?. 


Other thing, if I want to support say mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi and also normal and large screens, a drawable goes into the density folder but does the size of the screen need to be specified in some way as well? Thanks

Comment: @Levon: "but how would I determine a size in inches for that?" -- pick some likely device and measure 2/3rds of the screen. "does the size of the screen need to be specified in some way as well?" -- not usually. You could combine identifiers (e.g., `res/drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi/`) if there are cases where you want to use a different image on a different screen size/density combination. In the end, you will decide what drawables to use based on how they look when you test your app on a variety of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Drawable folders are meant for all kind of images.
hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi.xxhdpi are generally used to cover each and every device available in the market place.
nodpi folder is used to store images that can be used in any resolutions

For adding app icon try using the mipmap folders with all these above qualifiers for different size.

placing correct size images in correct folder will definitely work.

Comment: But, suppose I have an image which is 5000x5000 px, how should I make the distinctions between mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi?

Comment: create an image that fits best to your mdpi resolution device and taking mdpi as the reference density -- that is, 1 px on an mdpi display is equal to 1 dip  create other images using the scaling ratio. The ratio for asset scaling is:

ldpi | mdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi
0.75 | 1    |  1.5  | 2     | 3      | 4